# On WIX-made websites, how do I set a size limit for the member profile photo uploaded by users?

Tags: image, backend, size, hook, velo

I am using WIX’s built-in member page. WIX does not allow setting some photo size limits for photos uploaded by members. I’m trying to do this at the backend side by using the “beforeUpdate” hook for the public collection, i.e. “Members$PublicData”. I tried to replicate the approach used for custom member profile pages, but it doesn’t work.
Any help please?

Here is the code I have adopted.

```
export function Members$PublicData_beforeUpdate(item, context) {    
item.profPho.onCustomValidation((value, reject) => {
    let profImgFile = item.profPho;
    if (profImgFile.size > 6) {
        reject("Ain't is invalid");
    }
}, false)
}
```